# Proving that inequalities $\|a\|_{\infty} \leq \|a\|_2 \leq \sqrt{n} \|a\|_{\infty}$ are true and sharp.

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, radicals, absolute-value

For all $a=(a_1,\cdots,a_n)\in \mathbb{R}^n$ we consider

$$\|a\|_{\infty}= \displaystyle\max_{i\in \{1,\dots,n\}} |a_i|~~and~~~~\|a\|_2=\left(\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^n|a_i|^2\right)^{1/2}.$$

> Why we have
>   $$\|a\|_{\infty} \leq \|a\|_2 \leq \sqrt{n} \|a\|_{\infty},\;\forall\,a=(a_1,\cdots,a_n)\in \mathbb{R}^n?$$
>   And why the following inequalities are sharp?

Comment: The left hand side is trivial: just square both sides and note the the sum of squares contains the maximal element squared. The right hand side is also trivial: replace all squares by the square of the maximum and count. That they are sharp is seen by considering on the left hand side the standard unit vectors and on the right hand side vectors all of whose absolute values are the same.

Comment: At the left hand side you have only one element (the largest) from the sum, at the middle you have the whole sum and the right you are taking the largest element $n$ times.

Comment: @uniquesolution you love down votes I can see

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $i_0\in\{1,2,....n\}$ such that $|a_{i_0}|= \max\limits_{1\le i\le n}(|a_i|)$ then for all $ i\in\{1,2,....n\}$  we have  $|a_{i}|\le |a_{i_0}|$

$$|a_{i_0}|^2\le \sum_{i=1}^n|a_i|^2 \le \sum_{i=1}^n|a_{i_0}|^2 = n|a_{i_0}|^2 $$

taking the square root you get $$\|a\|_{\infty} \leq \|a\|_2 \leq \sqrt{n} \|a\|_{\infty}$$

The inequalities are sharp indeed taking $a= (1,0,0\cdots0)$ and $b= (1,1,1\cdots1)$

we get $$\color{red}{\|a\|_{\infty} = \|a\|_2 = 1~~~~and ~~~ = \|b\|_2 = \sqrt{n}\|b\|_{\infty}=\sqrt{n}}$$

Comment: Because at some point it contained errors.

Comment: At first, you didn't answer the part of the sharp inequalities. Then, you claimed that the choice of $a=(1,0,\cdots,0)$ shows sharpness, whereas in fact it only shows one side's sharpness. Then I edited your response and added the other vector $(1,1,\cdots,1)$, which you immediately edited yourself, writing - mistakenly - that both cases yield equality of the norms. Then you got fed up with all the comments and just deleted them, not before you took the liberty to comment about my mood, of all things. Finally, you keep editing this trivial problem over and over again, fussing about downvotes.

Comment: @uniquesolution $\bullet$

Comment: You seem to be in a bad mood. Which part is exactly $\bullet$? By the way, the max-norm of $b$ is one, not $\sqrt{n}$. Care to edit it? I promise you to give you back your vote when your answer will be correct.

Comment: @uniquesolution where did I wrote that about the norm of b? did you even read

Comment: The last line of your answer, after the words "we get" in red font, contains the statement that $\|b\|_\infty=\sqrt{n}$. That's a mistake. The norm is $1$.

Comment: @uniquesolution really please show me where or read again

Comment: @uniquesolution you mean this ?$\|b\|_2 = \sqrt{n}\|b\|_{\infty}=\sqrt{n}$

Answer (score 2):

Because $$\sqrt{\sum_{k=1}^n|a_k|^2}\le\sqrt{n\max\limits_{k}|a_k|^2}=\sqrt{n}\max\limits_{k}|a_k|$$